# pyqtgraph.opengl VS OpenGL.GL - how to display axis at PyQt5 OpenGL embedded widget

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

How to interact with `PyQt5.QtWidgets openGLWidget` using `pyqtgraph.opengl` instead of `OpenGL.GL`?
I need to make a next graphical output to `openGLWidget` on the PyQt5 form:

```
def plot_line(line):
    pl_line = np.array(line)
    color = (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 0.5)
    newline = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pl_line, color=color, width=5, antialias=False)
    w.addItem(newline)
    w.show()

line1 = [(-33.13, 1004.82, -125.7), (21.38, 1059.32, -162.03)]
plot_line(line1)
```

Here I have an example where I have a UI with a button and openGLWidget and I want to make a graphical output to openGLWidget which I defining at `plot_line()` function. How should I perform such output?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl

class app_1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(app_1,self).__init__()
        loadUi('Qt_test_Ui.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test GL app')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_push_b1)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_push_b1(self):
        self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL()


    def paintGL(self):
        w = self.openGLWidget
        axis = gl.GLAxisItem()  # show 3D axis 
        w.addItem(axis)


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
wid=app_1()
wid.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QOpenGLWidget is not a GLViewWidget so you can not replace it directly. The nearest option is that you use GLViewWidget in Qt Designer using the promotion, for it right click on QOpenGLWidget and select the option "Promote to ...", the following dialog will be opened and set with the following values:

[image]

Then press the add and Promote buttons. Doing the above the generated .ui is the following:

**Qt_test_Ui.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="GLViewWidget" name="openGLWidget"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>PushButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>GLViewWidget</class>
   <extends>QOpenGLWidget</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph.opengl</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Then it is used in the following way:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl

class app_1(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(app_1,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Qt_test_Ui.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test GL app')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_push_b1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_push_b1(self):
        axis = gl.GLAxisItem()
        self.openGLWidget.addItem(axis)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid=app_1()
    wid.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!!!!  Can I ask you related to this question "How to clear up  `openGLWidget` from geometry"?   `self.openGLWidget.removeItem()` or `self.openGLWidget.clear()` doesn't work

Comment: @NickPV What do you mean by eliminating geometry?

Comment: clear scene inside `openGLWidget` widget, clear including axis, just make it empty.

Comment: @NickPV Use `self.openGLWidget.removeItem(axis)` to remove a single item. If you want to remove all you must use: `for it in reversed(self.openGLWidget.items):
         self.openGLWidget.removeItem(it)
         del it`